# Applying CIFilter to NSView on OS X 10.10+

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, nsview, cifilter, nsviewanimation

I'm learning working with CoreAnimation.
I've tried to add some CIFilter to my NSView, but had a problem.

When I add filter to my view (view has NSButton as subview), it just clear all of its content, but it shouldn't!

Could you help me, what I'm doing wrong?

```
subView.wantsLayer = YES;
CIVector *center = [CIVector vectorWithX:NSMidX([subView bounds])
                                           Y:NSMidY([subView bounds])];
CIFilter *pointalize = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIPointillize"];
[pointalize setDefaults];
[pointalize setValue: @(1.0) forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey];
[pointalize setValue: center forKey: kCIInputCenterKey];
pointalize.name = @"pointalize";

[subView setContentFilters: @[pointalize]];
```